# BlueImp: How to set and send additional formData on destroy events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

When post form data, my backend require also data from _csrfToken field. How to setup and send this field data when user click to delete image on BlueImp jQuery plugin?

Here is what i'm trying without success, [following BlueImp Docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#destroy)

```
  $('#fileupload').on('fileuploaddestroy', function (e, data) {
    var val = $('input[name="_csrfToken"]').val();
    data.formData = {_csrfToken: val};
    });
```

what i see at chrome developer tools

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:hr
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:csrfToken=7fb73d62278fe3773c07ce1668f0af107d57a9bcdf7f2e1565dd8836907c9141c8ed9db2507636e5de7b8e6d9f6cdce3065b5d48100dd6b37d85568c3d8d0b89; CAKEPHP=l32oplq1i7qfapv3vtr6up7au1
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/apartmani/admin/albums/edit/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found solution by setting header:

```
 $('#fileupload').on('fileuploaddestroy', function (e, data) {
    var val = $('input[name="_csrfToken"]').val();
    //data.formData = {_csrfToken: val};
    data.headers={'X-CSRF-Token': val};
    });
```